# Disabling IPV6 on Always on availability group

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, clustering, network, ipv6

In our environment we only have one network adapters for the Replicas and IPV4 is being used. By default the IPV6 is also enabled. My question is will there be any problems if I unchecked IPV6 from the Adapter properties

Comment: Why fiddle if there is no issue and everything is running fine ?

Comment: Application is going slow at a certain period of time. Vendor asking if we can disable it.

Comment: That means they are stalling because whoever you are talking to doesn't know what is going on. I would immediately escalate upon receiving such a request from a vendor. Especially since I _know_ I'm using IPv6 and disabling it would interrupt production services.

Comment: the cluster is only using ipv4 not ipv6 but it was enabled as part of the default seryp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is will there be any problems if I unchecked IPV6 from the Adapter properties

Do not disable it, specially if you are not having any issue. WSFC *does* use IPV6 both for internal communication and can also be used for public network communication. Plus even if you disable IPV6 it is highly unlikely that cluster would not work or start giving some issue. I am sure that even if you disable IPV6 the WSFC would work but may be other network functionality might be affected since network is beyond scope of discussion I am not sure what might be affected but WSFC will work.

I would quote from [Failover Clustering and IPv6 in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2014/03/24/failover-clustering-and-ipv6-in-windows-server-2012-r2/)

> Should IPv6 be disabled for Failover Clustering?
>
> The recommendation for Failover Clustering and Windows in general,
>   starting in 2008 RTM, **is to not disable IPv6 for your Failover
>   Clusters**. The majority of the internal testing for Failover
>   Clustering is done with IPv6 enabled. Therefore, having IPv6 enabled
>   will result in the safest configuration for your production
>   deployment.